# Drag And Drop Plugin to Drag HTML Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I need a plugin to make edit on the pages of the site online, 
I need to be able to drag HTML Controls to the page.

I need a jquery plugin to do this - can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Online-Drag-Drop-Form-Builder/

This plugin I had used in my project.
This is smooth and easy to use.

Comment: thank you very much , do you have plugin for Page  or template Responsive Builder   ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Draggable` and `Droppable` functionality of jquery ui, check this links [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/). Here are some [examples](http://devheart.org/examples/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/1-getting-started-with-sortable-lists/)